# Linked Server Provider Shows Not Showing in both SQL Server Instances

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, linked-server, multiple-instances

I have two instances installed on my test server - a SQL Express instance and a SQL Developer instance.

I‌ just installed Oracle Db drivers (for an Oracle Db 11g instance)  so that I can link to an Oracle Database using Linked Servers.  The new provider ‌‌(OraOLEDB.Oracle) successfully shows in the SQL Express instance. So I'm able to successfully set up my linked server under that instance.

H‌owever, the provider doesn't show under the SQL Developer instance which is where I really wanted to use it.

Since the provider shows under SQL Express, I know the drivers are installed and presumably installed properly (e.g. right bit version, etc...)
‌
H‌ow do I the provider to show under SQL Developer as well.

Comment: What versions of SQL Server is each instance running? 32bit or 64bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
select @@version
```

on both instances.  Most likely you will find that one SQL instance is 32 bit and the other is 64 bit.  The Oracle Driver "bit version" has to match the sql instance "bit version".

Comment: I think you're right. I just realized that the instance was installed in my "C:\Program Files (x86)" which is for 32 bit installations. Also, the version returned as "Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR (KB3194714) - 12.0.5203.0 (Intel X86) ... Developer Edition on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (WOW64)". That's 32-bit correct?

Comment: Is there a 64-bit version of SQL Developer? I'd be willing to redo the install as Its relatively new. If not, how do I get around this?

Comment: I found the 64-bit version, installed it and now everything is working. Thanks